# How to use pseudo-arrays in POSIX shell script?

Tags: shell-script, array, posix

How to use pseudo-arrays in POSIX shell script?

I want to replace an array of 10 integers in a Bash script with *something* similar into POSIX shell script.

I managed to come across [Rich’s sh (POSIX shell) tricks](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html), on section *Working with arrays*.

What I tried:

```
save_pseudo_array()
{
    for i do
        printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/"
    done
    echo " "
}

coords=$(save_pseudo_array "$@")
set -- 1895 955 1104 691 1131 660 1145 570 1199 381
eval "set -- $coords"
```

I don't comprehend it, that's the problem, if anyone could shed some light on it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea is to encode the list of arbitrary strings into a scalar variable in a format that can later be used to reconstruct the list or arbitrary strings.

```
 $ save_pseudo_array x "y z" $'x\ny' "a'b"
'x' \
'y z' \
'x
y' \
'a'\''b' \

$
```

When you stick `set --` in front of that, it makes shell code that reconstructs that list of `x`, `y z` strings and stores it in the `$@` array, which you just need to `eval`uate.

The `sed` takes care of properly quoting each string (adds `'` at the beginning of the first line, at the end of the last line and replaces all `'`s with `'\''`).

However, that means running one `printf` and `sed` command for each argument, so it's pretty inefficient. That could be done in a more straightforward way with just one awk invocation:

```
save_pseudo_array() {
  LC_ALL=C awk -v q=\' '
    BEGIN{
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; i++) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, ARGV[i])
        printf "%s ", q ARGV[i] q
      }
      print ""
    }' "$@"
}
```

Comment: There's something to be said about portability vs efficiency here about the `printf ... | sed ...` vs `awk`, though: I don't remember all practical nuances of `awk` portability vs `sed`, but it's definitely a bigger minefield. If the target is just strictly POSIX, that might be fine, but if the target is practical portability to systems in practical use today, it might not be.

Comment: @mtraceur, AWK is [part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) and quite portable (if you avoid GNU extensions). (And I realise you’re not saying it’s not part of POSIX.)

Comment: @mtraceur, yes basically, the problem here would be the `/bin/awk` of Solaris that is the one with the API from Unix V7 in the late 70s (so without `-v`, `ARGV`...). That said on Solaris, there is a POSIX `awk` in `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, and more generally on Solaris you know that you can't expect much from the default environment and that you need to do a `PATH=$(getconf PATH):$PATH` to be able to do anything.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is there a particular reason you are using `LC_ALL=C` with your `awk` command? I didn't think you needed to do this unless you were comparing strings with the `==` operator.

Answer (score 12):

The basic idea is to use `set` to re-create the experience of working with indexed values from an array. So when you want to work with an array, you instead run `set` with the values; that’s

```
set -- 1895 955 1104 691 1131 660 1145 570 1199 381
```

Then you can use `$1`, `$2`, `for` etc. to work with the given values.

All that’s not much use if you need multiple arrays though. That’s where the `save` and `eval` trick comes in: [Rich’s `save` function](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html)¹ processes the current positional parameters and outputs a string, with appropriate quoting, which can then be used with `eval` to restore the stored values. Thus you run

```
coords=$(save "$@")
```

to save the current working array into `coords`, then create a new array, work with that, and when you need to work with `coords` again, you `eval` it:

```
eval "set -- $coords"
```

To understand the example you have to consider that you’re working with two arrays here, the one with values set previously, and which you store in `coords`, and the array containing 1895, 955 etc. The snippet itself doesn’t make all that much sense on its own, you’d have some processing between the `set` and `eval` lines. If you need to return to the 1895, 955 array later, you’d save that first before restoring `coords`:

```
newarray=$(save "$@")
eval "set -- $coords"
```

That way you can restore `$newarray` later.

---

<sup>¹ Defined as</sup>

```
save () {
for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/\$/' \\\\/" ; done
echo " "
}
```

Comment: Where is this `save` function defined?

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ in [Rich’s sh tricks](http://www.etalabs.net/sh_tricks.html), which is what the question is based on.